# Error message after installing Sublime Text 3

Tags: sh, sublimetext, fedora

I found on a website that I can install sublime 3 on Fedora 20 using the following command:
curl -L http://git.io/3Wr2CQ | sh
After running the command I can't open Sublime.
I get the following error:
`/usr/local/bin/subl: line 2: [: ==: unary operator expected`

Please see below a copy from the terminal:

```
    [pc@pc-z710 ~]$ curl -L http://git.io/3Wr2CQ | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100  1065  100  1065    0     0    543      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1040k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 7300k  100 7300k    0     0  2625k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 2625k
[sudo] password for red: 
mv: inter-device move failed: ‘/home/red/sublime_text_3/’ to ‘/opt/sublime_text_3’; unable to remove target: Directory not empty
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/bin/subl’: File exists
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  166k  100  166k    0     0   103k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  103k

Sublime Text 3 installed successfully!
Run with: subl
[pc@pc-z710 ~]$ subl
/usr/local/bin/subl: line 2: [: ==: unary operator expected
[pc@pc-z710 ~]$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Comment: Have you tried installing Sublime before, either version 2 or version 3? Also, the version of ST3 being installed by this script is outdated.

Comment: I'm the author of the script - I made some changes to it, please feel free to give it another try. You can find the updated script here: https://gist.github.com/simonewebdesign/8507139

Comment: It's the first time I've tried to install Sublime in any shape, form or version MattDmo. 
simone, can I simply install it or should I remove whatever I have now. If I have to remove it, can you also please tell me how?
I'm new (as is just switch from windows to linux) to linux so apologies for all the questions.

Comment: Hi @simone. I tried again and I got the same error. I used the instructiosn from your blog :|
'[pc@pc-z710 ~]$ curl -L git.io/sublimetext | sh
  '
'Sublime Text 3 installed successfully!'
Run with: subl
[pc@pc-z710 ~]$ subl
/usr/local/bin/subl: line 2: [: ==: unary operator expected
[rpc@pc-z710 ~]$ '
---------------------
I'm trying to install sublime text 3 on Fedora 20 64 bit.
I can see that I have the shortcut installed but it doesn't do anything when clicked.

Answer (score 8):

Change `${1}` into `"${1}"` so it evaluates to an empty string in shell when no parameter is given.

Also check the location of sublime_text. I had to change path from `/usr/local/sublime-text-3/sublime_text` to `/usr/local/sublime-text-3/sublime_text_3/sublime_text`.

Comment: thx I also had to change the path.  but i never got an icon in the menu though